# Is possible add a name for new terminal?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, gnome-terminal

Is there possible to add console name if I am using this part of code for run python script in new console on Linux?

```
string = "python3" + " " + par1
subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal", "--", "bash", "-c", string ])
```

Comment: Use `--title` option for that

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title